# Understanding some differences between using yield from generator comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, generator, yield

I have a scenario that behaves different when I implement a solution using a generator comprehension from when I use the `yield` keyword.

Here are the two examples:

Example A (this works):

```
def get_latest_products(self) -> Generator:
    first = True  # avoid appending the CSV header (first row)
    with open('path/to/my/file.csv')as file:
        file = get_csv_reader(file)
        for row in file:
            if not first:
                product = PageProduct(
                    page_name=row[0],
                    category_id=row[1],
                    product_id=row[2],
                    product_url=row[3],
                    product_name=row[4],
                    product_price=row[5],
                )
                yield product
            first = False
```

Example B (more elegant and would work if there was no I/O handling):

```
def get_latest_products(self) -> Generator:
    with open('path/to/my/file.csv') as file:
        file = get_csv_reader(file)
        return (
            PageProduct(
                page_name=row[0],
                category_id=row[1],
                product_id=row[2],
                product_url=row[3],
                product_name=row[4],
                product_price=row[5],
            ) for index, row in enumerate(file) if index > 0
        )
```

When the example B is implemented, which I think is more readable and elegant, I got: (when I call `next()`)

```
  File "/Users/xxx/xxx/collect_products.py", line 157, in <genexpr>
    return (
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

While the example A implementation works fine. Why?

Comment: The return exits the context manager, it's as simple as that.

Comment: Oh that's simple but still clever. No way to implement a generator comprehension for this case then? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define *and use* the generator inside the context of the `with` statement. The best way to do this is to have your method take an iterable (maybe a file handle, maybe something else) as an argument, instead of opening the file itself.

```
from itertools import islice


def get_latest_products(self, fh) -> Generator:
    f = get_csv_reader(fh)
    yield from (PageProduct(...) for row in islice(fh, 1, None))
```

The call the method from inside a `with` statement:

```
with open('path/to/my/file.csv', r) as f:
    for product in foo.get_latest_products(f):
        ...
```

This also makes testing much easier, as you can call `get_latest_products` with any iterable, rather than relying on a file in the file system.